# Debugging Trivia game in Python

Tags: python, debugging, text-files

### Creating function to print question, add choices to a list.

```
def print_et_list ():
    answer_list = []
    function = open ("modStory.txt","r")
    #Question
    question = function.readline()
    print question
    #Choices
    one = answer_list.append (function.readline())
    two = answer_list.append (function.readline())
    for item in answer_list:
        print item
    #Solution
    try:
        solution = int(function.readline())
    except:
        print "There's an error in the answer"

    ##for the blank line
    function.readline()


    return question, one, two, solution, function

  ##Function for prompting the user for an answer, comparing an answer, keeping score        and printing score.
def hey_user (solution):
    score = 0
    user_answer = int(raw_input ("Enter what you think the answer is, user.\n"))
    if user_answer == solution:
        print "You've got it right!"
        score = score + 1
    elif user_answer == 0:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "You've got it wrong."
    return score

def main ():
        question, one, two, solution, function = print_et_list()
        scoresofar = hey_user (solution)
        print "\nYour score is now", scoresofar
        while question:
            question, one, two, solution, function = print_et_list()
        function.close()

main ()


raw_input ("Hit enter to exit.")
```

For some reason I am unable to get this thing to loop properly. The code above infinte loops itself.
This following is the text file in question which is just garbled song lyrics. The program will run the first fragment properly, and will infinte loop the first fragment once the user gives the answer.

```
Can you carry my drink I have everything else
1 - I can tie my tie all by myself
2 - I'm getting tired, I'm forgetting why
2

is diving diving diving diving off the balcony
1 - Tired and wired we ruin too easy
2 - sleep in our clothes and wait for winter to leave
1

While it sings to itself or whatever it does
1 - when it sings to itself of its long lost loves
2 - I'm getting tired, I'm forgetting why
2
```

Comment: sorry, didn't see this earlier. 
The program is supposed to take a value from the user and add a point if it matches the solution. For example, in the first block, 2 is the correct answer. I'm supposed to match the user's entry with the "correct answer", add a point to "score" if right, and then go to the next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To correct the infinite loop, avoid to re-open the file on each call to `print_et_list()`

Try this (I renamed `function` into `file_handle` to be a little more explicit while reading the code)

```
import sys

def print_et_list (file_handle):
    answer_list = []
    #Question
    question = file_handle.readline()
    print question
    #Choices
    one = file_handle.readline()
    two = file_handle.readline()
    answer_list.append(one)
    answer_list.append (two)
    for item in answer_list:
        print item
    #Solution
    solution = None
    try:
        result = file_handle.readline()
        result.replace("\n","")
        solution = int(result)
    except:
        print "There's an error in the answer"

    ##for the blank line
    file_handle.readline()
    return question, one, two, solution

  ##file_handle for prompting the user for an answer, comparing an answer, keeping score        and printing score.
def hey_user (solution, score=0):
    user_answer = int(raw_input ("Enter what you think the answer is, user.\n"))
    print "you answered '%s'"%user_answer
    if user_answer == solution:
        print "You've got it right!"
        score += 1
    elif user_answer == 0:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "You've got it wrong."
    return score

def main ():
        file_handle = open ("modStory.txt","r")
        question, one, two, solution = print_et_list(file_handle)
        scoresofar = hey_user(solution)
        print "\nYour score is now", scoresofar
        while question:
            question, one, two, solution = print_et_list(file_handle)
            if question:
                scoresofar = hey_user(solution, scoresofar)
                print "\nYour score is now", scoresofar
        file_handle.close()

main ()


raw_input ("Hit enter to exit.")
```

This is not a perfect version, but it seems to work ;)

Comment: Hmm. When i do this, it runs, but now there seems to be an error in the Hey User function. 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'solution' referenced before assignment. It states line 35, the Hey User function seems to not like the solution variable. Any insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

`append` doesn't return anything, so `one` and `two` are `None`.